# Prove that if $p > 3$ is a prime then $2(p-3)! \pmod{p} =-1 \pmod{p}$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that if $p > 3$ is a prime then $2(p-3)! \pmod{p} =-1 \pmod{p}$..

I am totally lost; at first I thought this could be done by induction, but unfortunately this is not possible (at least I believe) because $p + 1$ won't be a prime so $P(n) =/> P(n+1)$.

I tried using modular arithmetic but I haven't gotten far.

Can anybody hint me here?

Comment: Have you heard of Wilson's theorem?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use it but I can't seem to transform (p-1) in (p-3)

Comment: hint : $$(p-1)(p-2)\equiv  (0-1)(0-2)\equiv  2\pmod{p}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with Wilsons's theorem $(p-1)!\equiv -1 \mod p$, and then try to make $(p-3)!$ appears in this identity...